# Tools for converting 3d model files (3ds/obj/whatever if it's an open format) to C arrays

Tags: c, opengl, graphics, 3d

I found [here](https://people.scs.fsu.edu/~burkardt/pl_src/obj2opengl/obj2opengl.html) a script which converts obj files into C header files with information required to render the model with OpenGL. I'd like something like this but I will need texture coordinates as well. The tool apparently doesn't do that.

Such a tool will save me a lot of time because I'd have to make my own program to extract data  so I can add the data to the arrays.

Loading models from the files during runtime would be ridiculous. It's far more sensible to store the information inside the program. That will cut down on the processing and bulk of the program as well as programming effort and time required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the two answers but I've found my own solution to this problem by using this tool:

http://www.heikobehrens.net/2009/08/27/obj2opengl/

Comment: Matthew this link shows nothing only display the intro of the author

Comment: It looks like the post was removed.

Answer (score 0):

"3D Exploration" did that, along with many other things. Maybe you could find a version somewhere, since the original site is down.

(and it wouldn't be ridiculous, it would only depend on the workflow used. But for a single developper AND small models, it can make sense, yeah. Just make sure you won't have to embed a 500Mb model in your .exe ...)

Answer (score 0):

Just use Blender (v2.49, www.blender.org) and write your own Python export script. It's really easy and free.